# Quiz options not displaying for my quiz app

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a quiz app and there is two main function:

1. fetchData

This function will fetch questions from a API and display everything to the webpage.

2. isCorrect

This function will check if the answer is correct typed by the user. If it is, add 1 to the score variable. But when the first function runs, it doesn't show me anything. My guess is that the option is not properly displayed or something. Here is my first function's code:

```
async function fetchData() {
  var getData = await fetch(url);
  var toJS = await getData.json();
  answer_container = toJS.results[0].correct_answer;
  var container = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < toJS.results[0].incorrect_answers.length; i++) {
    container.push(toJS.results[0].incorrect_answers[i]);
  }
  container.push(toJS.results[0].correct_answer);
  container.sort(func);

  function func(a, b) {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  }
  container.forEach(function(choices) {
    html_container.push(`
<option value=${choices}>
${choices}
</option>
`)
    console.log(choices);
  });
  document.getElementById('choice').add(html_container.join());
  if (toJS.results[0].type === 'boolean') {
    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML =
      `This question is a ${toJS.results[0].category} question <br>
It is a true/false question<br>
Difficulty level: ${toJS.results[0].difficulty} <br>
Question: ${toJS.results[0].question}<br>
`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML =
      `This question is a ${toJS.results[0].category} question <br>
It is a ${toJS.results[0].type} choice question <br>
Difficulty level: ${toJS.results[0].difficulty} <br>
Question: ${toJS.results[0].question}<br>
`;
  }
  document.getElementById('answer_element').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('answer_element').innerHTML = "The answer to this question is " + toJS.results[0].correct_answer;
}
fetchData();
```

I got this error on the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'HTMLSelectElement': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLOptGroupElement or HTMLOptionElement)'.

But I clearly added my options to a select element with an id of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

I'm assuming `line 23` is the error since it was the only `add` method shown. The error is caused by passing a string ([`html_container.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) to the [`add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) method, but it is [expecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add#parameters) an `HTMLOptGroupElement` or `HTMLOptionElement`. To fix this issue, you have at least two options: [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

---

### Solution 1: `createElement` with `innerHTML`

Use `document.createElement('option')` when creating the option element as follows:

```js
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = choices;
option.innerHTML = choices;
document.getElementById('choice').add(option);
```

---

### Solution 2: `innerHTML` only

Use `.innerHTML` to add the string to the select element's inner HTML as follows:

```js
// use += to append
document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML += html_container.join();
```